# How do I stretch an anchor with 2 images stacked on top of each other across the screen?

Tags: html, css

As weird as that sounds, I have an Anchor tag with 2 images of the same size stacked on top of each other. One being in HTML and the other being the a background image inside a div, that times 4 in a row. I would like these anchors to stretch and scale according to screen size while the images themselves stay on top of each other

The HTML:

```css
.gradient1 {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527) 27%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 87%), url(https://via.placeholder.com/230x220);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.gradient2 {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527) 27%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 87%), url(https://via.placeholder.com/230x220);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.gradient3 {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527) 27%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 87%), url(https://via.placeholder.com/230x220);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.gradient4 {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.527) 27%, rgb(0, 0, 0) 87%), url(https://via.placeholder.com/230x220);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.gallery {
  flex: 0%;
}

.thumbnails {
  display: flex;
}

.effect:hover {
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnails">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/230x220">
      <div class="gradient1"><img class="effect" src="/img/thumbnail/tn1.png"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="img/image2.gif">
      <div class="gradient2"><img class="effect" src="https://via.placeholder.com/230x220"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="img/image3.jpg">
      <div class="gradient3"><img class="effect" src="https://via.placeholder.com/230x220"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <a href="img/image4.jpg">
      <div class="gradient4"><img class="effect" src="https://via.placeholder.com/230x220"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[this is what I want this to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mevve.png)

Answer (score 0):

what seems to be the issue with your code? are the 3 images not showing up? if so, i think you're missing a "/" in your `<a href`'s before "img"